# UITabBar wont hide

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a UINavigationController in a UITabBarController, and I can't seem to get a pushed viewController's tabBar to hide.

I am using the following code to hide it:

Before it gets pushed:

`tpsv.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;`
 `tpsv.tabBarController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;`

viewWillAppear:

`self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;`

`AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

`[[[del tabController] tabBar]setHidden:YES];`

But none of the above work.

If you could tell me how to fix this, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void) hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        } 
        else 
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
        }

    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];





}

- (void) showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", view);

        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];

        } 
        else 
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 431)];
        }


    }

    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

Comment: you can put these functions in some global file and you just need call the hide function to hide the tabbarcontroller.. and show function to show the tabbarcontroller... you can call these methods like - [commonFunctions hideTabBar:self.tabbarcontroller];

Comment: I tried it in the viewController that I cant hide, and it would work either.

Answer (score 4):

You set this before you push the new view controller:

```
MyViewController *myVC = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
myVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];
```

[EDIT: comment re usage]

Just noticed you say you tried this. Not sure what else you're doing in the context of pushing your VC or configuring it but this does work fine. It's how I do this exact thing in my apps.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem with

```
myVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

It does'nt remove the tab bar in subsequent views. May be it's deprecated. You should'nt face this problem with the setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed: command. Try using the following for views:

```
MyViewController *myVC = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[myVC setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];
```