# Animating a UIView frame, subview UIScrollView doesn't always animate

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

In [this](http://screencast.com/t/YvjNf5Z1xMn) example.

I'm animating the PhotoViewerViewController's frame when I animate out the tabBarController (for fullscreen effect). The PhotoViewer uses a uiscrollview to generate the same sort of effect Apple's photos app does. For whatever reason sometimes it animates along with my PhotoViewer frame, and sometimes it doesn't.

You can see in the first example it jumps when increasing the frame size, but animates nicely when decreasing the frame size (and restoring the tab bar).

However in [this](http://screencast.com/t/UcgXROBcP1) example when the photo is vertical it jumps in both directions.

In both cases if I zoom in on the photo at all with the scrollview, it animates correctly in both directions.

I know the evidence is there, but I can't put my finger on what's happening here.

Here's my animation block:

```
void (^updateProperties) (void) = ^ {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = hidden ? 0.0f : 1.0f;
    self.navigationController.toolbar.alpha = hidden ? 0.0f : 1.0f;
    if (self.tabBarController) {

        int height = self.tabBarController.tabBar.bounds.size.height;
        for(UIView *view in self.tabBarController.view.subviews)
        {
            int newHeight;
            UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
            if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
                newHeight = hidden ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - height;
            } else {
                newHeight = hidden ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - height;
            }


            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, newHeight, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            } 
            else 
            {
                CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, newHeight);
                [view setFrame:newFrame];

                // update our VC frame with animation
                [self.view setFrame:newFrame];

            }

        }
    }

};
```

Code adapted from a post on SO: [UITabBar wont hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706536/uitabbar-wont-hide/5706711#5706711)

Full source on [github](https://github.com/sprynmr/PhotoViewer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, if animations sometimes work and sometimes don't, it's because in the latter case a delayed perform is causing them to be effectively cancelled by setting the property concerned to its final value.

In the particular case of `UIScrollView` it often happens that `-layoutSubviews` is called without animation one run loop after your animation blocks have closed. For this reason I usually try to avoid doing any layout in that method where I have a `UIScrollView` in the view hierarchy (because particularly prior to iOS 5, `UIScrollView` is really trigger-happy on setting itself to need layout).

I would recommend removing your call to `-[EGOPhotoImageView layoutScrollViewAnimated:]` from `-layoutSubviews` and add it to an overridden `-setFrame:` instead.

If you can target iOS4 and above, take a look at `UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews` too. Using a block-based animation with this as an option might just work without changing anything else.

Comment: Thanks. The latter didn't work, but I'll give a go with the former.

Comment: While I haven't solved it yet, I think you have pointed me in the right direction. I'm not sure if this particular transform is being triggered on the PhotoImageView itself, or the scroll that contains it.

Comment: Personally I would move all the logic for centering the contents of the scrollview to the scrollview subclass itself. There, you can override -setContentOffset: to perform layout rather than using the zoom delegate methods.

Comment: Yea good thought. I think I'm going to rewrite all the display logic for this class when I have a chance (once this project is out the door and I have some breathing room.) There's other little hiccups like a slight stutter when sliding images over, which I think is related to laying out subviews of other images during scrolling. I'll throw you your bounty when it lets me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your github code on iPad 4.2 and 4.3 simulators and it works fine... no image resizing whatsoever! There might be some version issues.
Also, I tried changing your animations block and the following serves the same purpose:

```
void (^updateProperties) (void) = ^ {
            self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = hidden ? 0.0f : 1.0f;
            self.navigationController.toolbar.alpha = hidden ? 0.0f : 1.0f; }
```

Let me know if I'm missing something :)

Comment: To test what I was demonstrating in the videos, you need to add it to a tabbarcontroller, and i'd recommend a good assortment of images from flickr when you build it. I can put together a sample if you need.