# Animating UIView frame size change with autoresizing subviews

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, subview

I have a UIView which contains two subviews. I would like to change the superview's frame size with an animation and have the subviews' sizes change in accordance with their autoresize masks.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Resize" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
CGRect frame = self.myView.frame;
frame.size.height += 30.0;
self.myView.frame = frame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The view `self.myView` is resized over 1 second as expected, but the subviews are resizing immediately. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I might make the subviews animate their resizing as well?

From my googling around, I think it might have something to with the `contentMode` property. Unfortunately, I'm not  really clear as to what that property does. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I figured out the issue after reading the answer to the following question: [Animating a UIView frame, subview UIScrollView doesn't always animate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647747/animating-a-uiview-frame-subview-uiscrollview-doesnt-always-animate)

I basically was doing some work after I scheduled the animation which was causing -`layoutSubviews` to be called on each of my subviews which automatically caused those views to be arranged at the end point of the animation. By scheduling my animation after this work was done I was able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 14):

It would have been hard for someone else to give you the correct answer w/o seeing your code though I would have asked you what you are doing after `[UIView commitAnimations]`. Nevertheless, glad you figured it out. I suggest you use the block animations. They make this type of mistake much easier to avoid by using a completion block. Example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect frame = self.myView.frame;
                     frame.size.height += 30.0;
                     self.myView.frame = frame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     // whatever you need to do when animations are complete
                 }];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the need to be compatible with older versions of iOS rules out block animations. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: makes sense. though the installed base of < 4.x is pretty tiny these days.